# call methods after javax.ws.rs.core.Application initialization

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy, servletcontextlistener

I use RestEasy to develop a web application. I have a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` and registers the REST services.
After the creation and (full) initialization of all the services I want to execute some methods of these services. These methods may call other methods of the service using the REST API.

The problem is that until the moment that my subclass of `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` is initialized (end of constructor) the REST API is not available (calls using REST API block) so it is not possible to call the methods after the service initialization. I also, tried using `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap` without success.

Also, `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized` seems to be executed earlier than the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application.init` so there are no references to the service objects.

In general, I am looking for a clean way to execute code right after the services are available/deployed. Is there any way to be notified for such an event?